# Trying to center asp imagebuttons inside div

Tags: css, html, imagebutton, centering

I am trying to build a usercontrol consisting of 5 imagebuttons that have to stack ontop of each other inside a div. The images are of varying size.
How do i get them to center themselves inside the containing div?

```
<div class="ButtonBox">
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" 
    ImageUrl="/css/images/lightbulb.png" CssClass="button" />
<br/>

<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" 
    ImageUrl="/css/images/testimonials.png" CssClass="button" />
<br/>
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton3" runat="server" 
    ImageUrl="/css/images/templates.png" CssClass="button" />
<br/>
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton4" runat="server" 
    ImageUrl="/css/images/video.png" CssClass="button" />
<br/>
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton5" runat="server" 
    ImageUrl="/css/images/audio.png" CssClass="button" />
<br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can centre your image buttons with a bit of CSS.

```
.ButtonBox input{
   display:block;
   margin:0 auto;
}
```